# get user data from its session Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> **TABLES**

**Pengguna**
[image: Pengguna]

**MAHASISWA**
[image: Mahasiswa]

I have 2 tables, `Pengguna` and `Mahasiswa`, table `pengguna`is a table contain data for user that can be log in into the website while table `mahasiswa` contain user data such as name, email, telephone etc.

then i want user that has been logged in to show their credential information that has been exist in table `mahasiswa`. let's say i logged in with **username "123"** with **id_pengguna "3"** that's mean that **my name is "Mirza"** and **my nim is "123"** and etc.

the question is how can i set the session of the logged user and get the user information from table `mahasiswa`? all i can do is show the first table from `mahasiswa` instead getting the data from the user logged in session, below are the `controller`, `model` and `view`

> **Model**

```
<?php
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class MProfile extends CI_Model{
       function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->database();
       }
       function read($cond, $ordField, $ordType){
          if($cond!=null){
             $this->db->where($cond);
          }
          if($ordField!=null){
             $this->db->order_by($ordField, $ordType);
          }
       $query = $this->db->get('mahasiswa');
       return $query;
       }
   }
```

> **CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Profil extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('MProfile');

    }

    public function index(){
        $data['menu4'] = true;
        /*$this->sessionOut();*/
        $this->session->userdata('idpengguna');
        $data['query'] = $this->MProfile->read(null, 'nim', 'ASC');

        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('profil_page', $data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }

}
```

> **VIEW**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
        $nim = $this->session->userdata['loggedin']['nim'];
    }
?>
<ul class="category-t">
    <?php foreach ($query->result() as $result){}?> 
    <li><?php echo $result->nim;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $result->nama_mahasiswa;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $result->email;?></li>
    <li><?php echo $result->telepon;?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simply use the table joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, you can create a new query selecting data from your `mahasiswa` table.

Add this to your controller

```
$data["row"] = $this->Mprofile->getmahasiswa();
```

In your model

```
function getmahasiswa(){
   $idpengguna = $this->session->userdata('idpengguna');

   $this->db->where('id_pengguna', $idpengguna);
   $q = $this->db->get('mahasiswa');
   return $q->row();
}
```

And in your view

```
<ul class="category-t">
   <li><?php echo $nim;?></li>
   <li><?php echo $nama_mahasiswa;?></li>
   <li><?php echo $email;?></li>
   <li><?php echo $telepon;?></li>
</ul>
```

Add this at the top of your view

```
<?php
   if ($row){
       $nim= $row->nim;
       $nama_mahasiswa = $row->nama_mahasiswa;
       $email = $row->email;
       $telepon= $row->telepon;
   } else {
       $nim =
       $nama_mahasiswa =
       $email = 
       $telepon = "";
   }
?>
```

Comment: it's said trying to get property of non-object, so in my view instead `<?php echo $row->nim;?>` i did this `<?php echo $row['nim'];?>` but it has no result at all, am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @MirzaChilman sorry missed underscores at `$this->db->where('idpengguna', $idpengguna);` should be `$this->db->where('id_pengguna', $idpengguna);`

Comment: still i've got the same issue

Comment: yes i did and still the same issue, and when i called it with another way like using `$row['nim'];`, there's no result at all, how to change it into an object?

Comment: do i need `<?php foreach(bla bla bla){}>`?

Comment: @MirzaChilman if youre test it when not logged in, so there is no idpengguna session, and the query won't work.

Comment: did whtau just told me to, but same, no result at all, the page just goes blank with no data at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106683/discussion-between-yoshioka-and-mirza-chilman).

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query in model and will get the data from both the tables and then can use it. send id to the model of the id_pengguna. This id will be the user **id** for comparison 
**Model**

```
function getdata($id){
    $query = "select peng.*, masha.* 
    from pengguna peng join mashasiswa masha 
    on id_pengguna where masha.id_pengguna = $id";
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
$data['result'] = $this->model_name->getdata($id);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: can u provide more complete answer?

Comment: first you will get the `id` from the table where you actually login in. then pass that id to the model.

Comment: id_pengguna this is the id you need to get. and then pass through the controller. You got it.